# nginx: http to https not working on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, docker, nginx, https, reverse-proxy

I've got this nginx configuration to redirect http to https:

```
# http redirects to https
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    ...
}
```

It works properly on firefox. If I add in `/etc/hosts` entry like:

`127.0.0.1       my-custom-domain.com` to make sure I have domain that was never used, in firefox if I enter `my-custom-domain.com`, I get this:

[image]

Works as expected, it redirects to https.

But if I do the same on chrome, I get this:

[image]

Chrome only opens `https` one if I explicitly enter `https://my-custom-domain.com`.. Not sure why it behaves differently on chrome.

It looks like this issue is related with nginx docker image. I was not able to reproduce this with nginx installed locally. Though nginx images with tags `nginx:1.18.0`, `nginx:1.23.0`, `nginx:1.23.0-alpine` all had same issue.

P.S. I read some people say that `server_name` must not be `_` and have specific name, but it works the same even if I enter `sever_name my-custom-domain.com;`

P.S.S I'm using `1.23.0-alpine` nginx docker image.

**Update**

Did `curl -I my-custom-domain.com`

On non docker nginx, I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Fri, 15 Jul 2022 12:17:50 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://my-custom-domain.com/
```

On docker nginx I get:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to my-custom-domain.com port 80: Connection refused
```

Comment: Is it Correctly redirecting with other Servers , eg http://superuser.com/ ? OR Is only your Nginx Server not redirecting ? What I mean : It may be your web-browser Issue , not your Server Issue !!

Comment: Yes, its redirecting correctly. As I said in question, I only have issue if I use docker nginx. I if I use non docker nginx installed locally, then redirect works fine.

Comment: You should execute "curl -I http:/...." to check the HEADERS : you should get "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" & "location: https://...." in both Docker Installation and local Installation. In case that works, you could try with other web-browsers & then maybe raise a bug against Google Chrome.

Comment: @Prem I tried your suggestion. So non docker one works correctly. Though docker one, gives connection refused.. (posted in my question as well) Not sure why. So might not be chrome related. Though firefox is still able to redirect..

Comment: Glad to help you with troubleshooting the issue & Pointing to curl ! It is incorrect to say that firefox can redirect : It was actually not trying HTTP Port 80 at all & was using HTTPS Port 443 all along ! Chrome was trying Port 80 & failing !

Comment: Thanks. Well, how firefox was trying 443 then? I made sure to use new domain, so it would not use address from history. Or does it mean firefox just try 443 by default?

Comment: In web-browser, you have to type "http://my-custom-domain.com" , not just "my-custom-domain.com" , then you would have caught the Issue yourself ! Your firefox configuration adds https:// Prefix & gets the "Potential Risk" : Your Chrome configuration adds http:// Prefix & gets "No Connection" !

Comment: I see, so firefox uses `https` by default and chrome `http` (if nothing is specified).

Comment: Chrome checks whether it is local Domain to Prefix HTTP ! [[ "IP addresses, single label domains, and reserved hostnames such as test/ or localhost/ will continue defaulting to HTTP." : https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/google/google-chrome-90-released-with-https-as-the-default-protocol/ ]]

Comment: That link says it should be https by default, but it was not. Weird

Comment: It says it is "HTTP" for local Domain 127.0.0.1 , like your Example ; Otherwise it is HTTPS !!

Comment: Well it did not work on normal IPs with DNS. I only later reproduced this locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So issue was quite simple. Nginx is working correctly, but I was not exposing `80` port from docker, only `443`.

Basically added `80:80` in ports and now chrome redirects this as well (in `docker-compose.yml`):

```
ports:
  - 443:443
  - 80:80
```